# How can I stop selecting verts I cant see through separate mesh?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, select

I would swear up and down It wasnt doing this before because it suddenly started happening and Im losing my marbles. Im trying to edit the back of these shorts in edit mode. I will select Verts and somehow it goes through the body mesh and grabs the front of the shorts too. Im using lasso tool. I dont have x ray on. I tried gpu depth picking on and off both same result. Please help me, I have a lot of clothes to edit.
[image: back of shorts]
[image: front verts that got selected as well]

Comment: It might be a bug 

Comment: If you hide the body and front vertices are seen from back side in time of selection, so they are selected as well. I don't think Blender ever considered other objects in viewport as blockators.

Comment: Hi. What version of Blender are you using? Could you upload a .blend file to https://blend-exchange.com/ with just the problem shorts in it and add it to your question? Maybe someone could see from that what is causing this odd behavior.